# BFS Function Using Scala

Tags: scala, breadth-first-search

I'm trying to implement a bread first search function in scala. But I'm stuck with this error :

> Cannot resolve overloaded method 'enqueue'

Here is what I have so far:

```
 sealed trait BinaryTree[+A]
 case object Empty extends BinaryTree[Nothing]
 case class Node[+A](value: A, left: BinaryTree[A], right: BinaryTree[A]) extends BinaryTree[A]
    
 val t = Node(3,Node(4, Node(6,Empty,Node(11,Empty,Empty)),Node(7,Node(12,Empty,Empty),Empty)),Node(5,Node(8,Node(13,Empty,Empty),Empty),Node(9,Empty,Empty)))
    
 def bfs(root: Node[Int]): Unit = {
    val q = new mutable.Queue[Node[Int]]()
    var node = root
    
    q.enqueue(node)
    while (q.nonEmpty) {
      node = q.dequeue()
      print(node.elem + " ")
      if (node.left != null) q.enqueue(node.left)
      if (node.right != null) q.enqueue(node.right)
    }
  }
```

How can I make this function work?

Comment: I don't get that error, rather I get some expected type errors since you are just assuming you will always get back a `Node`: https://scastie.scala-lang.org/BalmungSan/RuRvgxxUQeW3kGimensVkA/3 - You need some pattern matching instead of checking for `null`

Comment: It should be `node.value` first of all. This code has a lot of discrepancies. Please post a reproducible example first

Answer (score 1):

`node.left` is `BinaryTree`, but `queue.enqueue` expects a `Node`, so, it can't resolve it.
Also, you should not be using vars, nulls, imperative loops or mutable structures. If you are learning scala anyway, might as well learn to use it the right way.

```
def bfs(root: [Node[Int]]) = {
  @tailrec
  def loop(queue: Queue[BinaryTree[Int]]): Unit =  queue.dequeueOption match {
    case None => 
    case Some((Empty, q)) => loop(q) 
    case Some((node: Node[Int], q)) => 
      print(s"${node.value} ")
      loop(q.enqueue(node.left).enqueue(node.right)
  }
  loop(Queue.empty[BinaryTree[Int]].enqueue(root))
  println() 
}
```